# How to enable PDO_MYSQL for CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm trying to learn the Symfony framework for PHP but having issues with the command line version of php.

When trying to create the database tables:

```
./symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't locate driver named mysql
```

This is only an issue with the command line version of php.  I've had doctrine working no problem.

After quickly reading up on the problem, it seems I need to enable PDO_MYSQL for the CLI installation of php.  I've looked in the php.ini file and there does not appear to be a relevant entry for it.

Is there any easy way to make the CLI version use exactly the same configuration of my LAMPP configuration, in order to minimise complications in the future?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting pdo\_mysql driver to work in CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001316/getting-pdo-mysql-driver-to-work-in-cli)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `ubuntu`+`mysql` (individual install non-lamp) and `php cli` via `apt`:

`sudo apt-get install php5-cli`

PDO is installed by default but the appropriate db driver (`mysql` in my case) wasn't installed. This can be verified from the command line `php --ri pdo` which results in:

```
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => [ blank ]
```

To rectify this for `mysql`, install the `php5-mysql` module via

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Obviously, do this after you've installed `php5-cli`. If you're using another db (e.g. `postgres` or `odbc`) look for the appropriate module name via

`sudo apt-cache search php5`

Sorry, crossposted from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001316/getting-pdo-mysql-driver-to-work-in-cli/7564362#7564362).

Comment: I just did exactly what you wrote but still didn't get php5-mysql to show up as a PDO driver.

Answer (score 2):

I think these answers are a bit old. Correct answer would be sudo apt-get install php-mysql. Executing php5-mysql would result in no package found, specially on machines which has php7-cli installed. As mentioned problem is that though PDO support is enabled, no driver installed. I simply resolved it by executing the above command.

Answer (score 0):

check the php.ini in your apache folder and copy the PDO information to the php.ini in your php folder.

In my lampp configuration I just have 'extension=pdo.so' in php.ini