# reverse database won't work from terminal (PROPEL / BAKE CAKEPHP)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, propel, cakephp-bake

I've been trying to generate model classes from a local database using both propel and bake for cakephp , it seems that i have the same problem :

When I try to acces the database through bake or propel it gives me an error that it can't open the connection:

So I tried this :
I try to acces the database from the application using pdo it works just fine!!!
When I tried to acces database through terminal it's also working !!!

I really don't know what's the problem here !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have a separate php.ini config file for CLI and pdo_mysql is not loaded for CLI.

Comment: Thanks the problem was that i didn't have a pdo_mysql driver installed for my php5
but your answer made me find out
I also used this link to solve my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7564426/3004667