# propel 2, mysql - No errors from reverse, no schema.xml created

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I installed propel2 (~2.0@dev) with composer in my web project yesterday and spent the afternoon trying to get it to reverse engineer my existing mysql db.

First, I tried following the directions on:

http://propelorm.org/documentation/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases.html

But kept getting an "unable to connect" error:

```
./propel reverse "mysql:host={mysql domain};dbname={my db name};user={username};password={password}" --verbose
There was an error building XML from metadata: Unable to open connection
Schema reverse engineering failed.
```

So I went back to the documentation, and thought that maybe I need a propel.php config file.  So I copied from the example, filling in the appropriate info for my db, and came up with this:

```
<?php

return [
    'propel' => [
        'database' => [
            'connections' => [
                'mpginfo' => [
                    'adapter'    => 'mysql',
                    'classname'  => 'Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper',
                    'dsn'        => 'mysql:host={mysql domain};dbname={my db name}',
                    'user'       => '{username}',
                    'password'   => '{password}',
                    'attributes' => []
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'runtime' => [
            'defaultConnection' => 'mpginfo',
            'connections' => ['mpginfo']
        ],
        'reverse' => [
            'connection' => 'mpginfo'
        ],
        'generator' => [
            'defaultConnection' => 'mpginfo',
            'connections' => ['mpginfo']
        ]
    ]          
];
```

Once I created this propel.php file and re-ran the reverse command, I no longer receive the "Unable to open connection" error, but I also see no output whatsoever!  I do not see a schema.xml file being created, and I don't see anything indicating that the command even ran.

Just to double check, I read [How to enable PDO_MYSQL for CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443562/how-to-enable-pdo-mysql-for-cli/7564426#7564426) and verified that the mysql driver for PDO is installed and enabled on my server:

```
$ php --ri pdo

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with my setup?  Are there other config files that I need to create?  How can I get some output for further debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I kept my config file, ran `--verbose` like [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25509788/1396649) suggested, and noticed that my schema.xml had been dropped in `generated-reversed-database/schema.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the config file, then use single quotes.

```
$ propel reverse --verbose 'mysql:host=domain;dbname=mydbname;user=username;password=password'
```

I was having exactly the same issue and this resolved it.

Comment: I just tried that again (moved to a new folder, got rid of the propel.php config file) and ran with single quotes.  I still get the error `./propel reverse --verbose 'mysql:host=domain;dbname=mydbname;user=username;password=password'
There was an error building XML from metadata: Unable to open connection
Schema reverse engineering failed.`

It did create a `generated-reversed-database` directory, but it is just an empty directory.

Comment: If you haven't already run `propel reverse --help` maybe you'll see something else in there that will give you a clue.  That's where I found the single quotes issue.  I gave up on this eventually, every single step just produces more errors.  Totally not worth the time to debug it.